Show that the Euclidean closed unit ball $B$ is the only self-polar set in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
The Euclidean closed unit ball $B$ is defined by $$B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid \|x\| \le 1 \}$$
and a polar set of $S$ is defined by $$S^o = \{c \in ((\mathbb{R}^d)^* \mid c \cdot x \le 1, \forall x \in S\} \subseteq (\mathbb{R^d})^*.$$
We know that $B = B^o$ and if $S = S^o$, then $S$ is self-polar.
Now I'm trying the following:
Let's show the uniqueness of $S = S^o \Leftrightarrow S = B$.
Suppose $S$ is any self-polar set and $S = S^o$. We know that $B = B^o$, so $S$ must be of a similar form $\|x\| \le r$ with $r \ge 1$.
But now, if $r > 1$ there would exist some $s \in S^o$ such that $s \cdot x > 1$ for some $x \in S$.
Is this the right way to proof it?

As you define it $B$ is not self-polar: it contains 0, but $B^0$ by definition doesn't (unless $(\mathbb{R}^d)^*$ means something else than $\mathbb{R}^d \setminus {0}$, in which case you should clarify this). Also, the empty set is obviously self-polar so you should probably exclude it.

Anyway, "we know that $B = B^o$, so $S$ must be of a similar form [...]" is not a valid argument: that's basically what you're trying to show! It's not clear at all that $S$ should be of this form from the get-go.

@BenSteffan I'm pretty sure the star means the dual space (which in this case is identified with the base space, as usual for Euclidean spaces).

@lisyarus That seems like a reasonable interpretation; if you also have a canonical guess for what $c \cdot x$ is supposed to mean in that case I'll be happy.

@BenSteffan probably the evaluation of $c$ in $x$

First, let's rewrite the condition $S=S^o$ in the following way, without explicitly mentioning $S^o$for convenience:

$\forall x,y\in S: x\cdot y \leq 1$
$\left(\forall x\in S: c\cdot x \leq 1 \right) \Rightarrow c\in S$

Now, the first condition immediately implies that $$x\in S \Rightarrow x\cdot x\leq 1 \Rightarrow \|x\|\leq 1 \Rightarrow S\subset B$$
So, $S$ is contained in $B$. For the inclusion in the other direction, consider some $c\in B$ and $x \in S$. Then, by Cauchy–Schwarz:
$$c\cdot x \leq \|c\|\cdot \|x\| \leq 1\cdot 1 = 1$$
which, by the second condition above, implies that $c \in S$. Therefore, $B\subset S$, and thus $S=B$.
